# extjs 3 - add progressbar and image in property grid

Tags: extjs, progress-bar, extjs3, propertygrid

Is it possible to implement progressbar in property grid in extjs 3? How do I add an image in property grid?

I have a value in percentage and I want to represent that in progressbar (its uneditable).

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
//==== Progress bar 1 ====
var pbar1 = new Ext.ProgressBar({
    id:'pbar1',
    width:300
});

var grid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
  title: 'Properties Grid',
  autoHeight: true,
  width: 300,
  renderTo: 'grid-ct',
  bbar: pbar1, //You can set the progress bar as the property girds bottom toolbar.
  customRenderers: {
    Available: function(v){
         return '<img src="path to image" />';
    }
  }, //This would render the image into the Available property.
  source: {
      "(name)": "My Object",
      "Created": new Date(Date.parse('10/15/2006')),
      "Available": false,
      "Version": .01,
      "Description": "A test object"
  }
});
```

When using customRenderers to render the image
`The name of the renderer type should correspond with the name of the property that it will render` For more see the [API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/).

Comment: hi thanks for replying. Image in property grid works great (make c small in CustomRenders). But is there any other way to add progressbar in property grid? I want to add it as a value. For now, I am just using an image to act as a progressbar. Regards

Comment: i Did not know you actually add the progress bar to a cell in the property grid. im not sure you will be able to do this. If I think of something I will post here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first thing I though about. But it's still not so user friendly as it's render progressbars after grid is rendered.

This is custom renderer for your progress column:

```
renderer: function( value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store ) {
                var id = Ext.id();
                (function(){
                    var progress = new Ext.ProgressBar({
                        renderTo: id,
                        value: progress_value
                    });
                }).defer(25);
                return '<div id="'+ id + '"></div>';
            }
```

It renders `<div id="generated-id"/>` and then renders generated progressbar into this `div`.

It would be better to use some kind of closure to create progressbar only once and to return it's html via custom renderer as in the example above, but unfortunately I don't know yet how to do it in Ext.js 3. As for Ext.js 4 you can see this thread at [sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?187168-Progress-Bar-inside-a-Grid-cell)